# What is the best way to directly return relations (one-to-many) value instead its Id?

Tags: laravel

How can I directly return the represented relations (specific) value out of the box without any further processes ?

Lets say I have tables and relations like below:

```
user
id name status_id
1  Jane 0
2  Joe  1

status
id title
1  pending
2  accepted
```

Here user belongsTo status and status hasMany users.

```
public function status()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Status');
}
```

What I mean is instead this response (with eager load):

```
{ 
   {"id":"1", "user":"Jane","status_id":"1", "status":{"id":"1", "title":"pending"} }, 
   {"id":"2", "user":"Joe", "status_id":"2", "status":{"id":"2", "title":"accepted"} }
}
```

Iam looking for this:

```
{ 
   {"id":"1", "user":"Jane","status":"pending" }, 
   {"id":"2", "user":"Joe", "status":"accepted" }
}
```

PS: I am not sure if this was asked before, at least I could'nt find any. This could be asked in different ways.

Comment: Defining an accessory is best way to handle this. But I wander if a user may have multiple statuses at one point.... I mean do you really need oneToMany relation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) which transfers the relationship to a custom field, then hide the relationship itself from JSON responses:

```
protected $hidden = [ 'userStatus' ];
protected $with = [ 'userStatus' ]; // Always load it eagerly

public function userStatus()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Status'); // I'm assuming this is what you actually have
}

public function getStatusAttribute() {
    return $this->userStatus->title;
}

protected $appends = [ 'status' ];
```